# Map is always getting null value when i access locMap

Tags: apex, batch, controller

```
global with sharing class InventoryCountBatch  implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id , Name , Price__c From Charge_Item__c');
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext Bc, List<Charge_Item__c> scope){
        Set<Id>chargeIds = new Set<Id>();   
        Map<Id, List<Line_Item__c>> lineItmMap = new Map<Id,List<Line_Item__c>>();
        Map<Id, List<Line_Item__c>> chargeItmMap = new Map<Id,List<Line_Item__c>>();
        Map<Id, Map<Id, List<Line_Item__c>>> locMap = new Map<Id,Map<Id, List<Line_Item__c>>>();
        Map<Map<Id, Id>, Map<Integer,Integer>> locMonthMap = new Map<Map<Id, Id>, Map<Integer,Integer>>();

        for(Charge_Item__c chargItm : scope){
            chargeIds.add(chargItm.id);
        }
        List<Line_Item__c> lineItemList = [Select id , Name, Charge_Item__c, Start_Time__c, End_Time__c, Reservation_line__c, Reservation_line__r.Location__c From Line_Item__c Where Charge_Item__c IN:chargeIds];
        List<Location__c> locationList = [Select id, Name From Location__c];
        for(Location__c loc : locationList){
            List<Line_Item__c>lineItmList = new List<Line_Item__c>();
            for(Line_Item__c lineItm : lineItemList){
                if(loc.id == lineItm.Reservation_line__r.Location__c){

                    if(lineItm.Start_Time__c !=Null && lineItm.Start_Time__c.Date().year() == System.today().Year() ){
                        //Integer month =lineItm.Start_Time__c.Date().month();
                        lineItmList.add(lineItm);
                        //system.debug('month is---'+month);
                    }
                    lineItmMap.put(lineItm.Reservation_line__r.Location__c, lineItmList);  
                }
            }   
        }

        List<Inventory_Count__c> inventryCountList = new List<Inventory_Count__c>();
         Map<Id,List<Line_Item__c>> lineChargeMap = new Map<Id,List<Line_Item__c>>();
        List<Line_Item__c> lineItmList1 = new List<Line_Item__c>();
        for(Location__c loc : locationList){
            lineItmList1 = lineItmMap.get(loc.id);
            lineChargeMap = new Map<Id,List<Line_Item__c>>();
            if(lineItmList1 != null && !lineItmList1.isEmpty()){
                for(Charge_Item__c chargeItm : scope){
                    List<Line_Item__c>lineItmsList = new List<Line_Item__c>();
                    for(Line_Item__c lineItm : lineItmList1){
                        if(chargeItm.id == lineItm.Charge_Item__c){
                            lineItmsList.add(lineItm);
                            lineChargeMap.put(chargeItm.id, lineItmsList);
                            locMap.put(loc.id,lineChargeMap);
                        }  
                    } 

                }
            }
        }


        List<Integer> monthArray = new List<Integer>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        Map<Integer,Integer> lineMonthMap;
        Map<Id,Id> locChargeMap;
        Integer count =0;
        List<Line_Item__c> lineItemsList ;
        List<Line_Item__c> lineItemsSize;
        for(Location__c loc : locationList){
            Map<Id, List<Line_Item__c>> numMap = locMap.get(loc.id);
            for(Charge_Item__c chargeItm : scope){ 
                locChargeMap = new Map<Id,Id>();              
                if(numMap != null && !numMap.isEmpty()){   
                    lineItemsList = new List<Line_Item__c>();
                   lineItemsList = numMap.get(chargeItm.id);
                    System.debug('No of time used---'+lineItemsList);
                    if(lineItemsList != null && lineItemsList.Size() >0){ 
                    //Integer count = lineItemsList.size();
                    lineItemsSize = new List<Line_Item__c>();
                    for(Line_Item__c lineItm : lineItemsList){
                        for(Integer str : monthArray){
                            lineMonthMap = new Map<Integer, Integer>();
                            if(lineItm.Start_Time__c.Date().month() == str){ 
                                lineItemsSize.add(lineItm);
                                count =lineItemsSize.size();
                                locChargeMap.put(loc.id,chargeItm.id);
                                lineMonthMap.put(str,count);
                                locMonthMap.put(locChargeMap,lineMonthMap);
                                System.debug('locChargeMap--'+locChargeMap);
                                System.debug('lineMonthMap--'+lineMonthMap);
                                System.debug('locMonthMap--'+locMonthMap);

                               /* Inventory_Count__c invCount = new Inventory_Count__c();
                                invCount.Charge_Item__c = chargeItm.id;
                                String startPeriod = '0'+lineItm.Start_Time__c.Date().month()+'/01/'+System.today().Year();
                                String endPeriod = '0'+lineItm.Start_Time__c.Date().month()+'/29/'+System.today().Year();
                                invCount.Period_Start__c = Date.parse(startPeriod);
                                invCount.Period_End__c = Date.parse(endPeriod);
                                invCount.Cost__c = (chargeItm.Price__c*lineItemsSize.size());
                                invCount.Count__c = lineItemsSize.size();      
                                invCount.Location__c = loc.Name; 
                                inventryCountList.add(invCount);*/

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                }   
            }    
        }
        System.debug('locMonthMap---'+locMonthMap);
        Map<Id,Id> getMapVal;
        Map<Integer,Integer> mapOfMonth;
         for(Location__c loc : locationList){
            for(Charge_Item__c chargeItm : scope){          
                getMapVal = new Map<Id,Id>();
                 mapOfMonth  = new Map<Integer,Integer>();
                getMapVal.put(loc.id, chargeItm.id);

                System.debug('getMapVal---'+getMapVal);
                mapOfMonth = locMonthMap.get(getMapVal);
                System.debug('mapOfMonth---'+mapOfMonth);                                                
                if(mapOfMonth != null && !mapOfMonth.isEmpty()){
                    for(Integer str : monthArray){
                      if(mapOfMonth.get(str) != null && mapOfMonth.get(str) >0){
                            Inventory_Count__c invCount = new Inventory_Count__c();
                            invCount.Charge_Item__c = chargeItm.id; 
                            String startPeriod = str+'/01/'+System.today().Year();
                            String endPeriod =  str+'/31/'+System.today().Year();
                            invCount.Period_Start__c = Date.parse(startPeriod);
                            invCount.Period_End__c = Date.parse(endPeriod);
                            invCount.Cost__c = (chargeItm.Price__c*mapOfMonth.get(str));
                            invCount.Count__c =mapOfMonth.get(str);       
                            invCount.Location__c = loc.Name; 
                            inventryCountList.add(invCount);   
                       }
                    }
                }
             }
         }

        insert inventryCountList;  
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

locMap is getting null value when i access it using  getMapVal  map and store it  mapOfMonth. mapOfMonth is getting null always , even my locMap has filled all data that is map of ids and map of interger type values.
Please give solution of this. When i debug the locMap, it contains data + {already output = already output} , i think it cause be an issue for that.

Comment: This is a lot of data-dependent code to wade through. You can help us help you be being as specific as possible about what you know about the problem. For example, identify specific lines where the state of `locMap` is not what you expect, and _show us_ what it actually contains and what you expect it to contain. On a quick read I see lots of reasons why `locMap` might be empty if your data doesn't match what you think it contains.

Comment: another tip -- you have so much nesting of loops and conditionals. This makes reading and debugging such code very difficult

Comment: Did you debugged using debug logs? Is your map populating?

Comment: Yes @MuzammilBajaria I debugged the Map , That's populating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Map is filling the all values into the locMonthMap. Could you please change your Map that name is locMonthMap that type is `Map<Map<Id, Id>, Map<Integer,Integer>>`  converts into locMonthMap `Map<Map<String, String>, Map<Integer,Integer>>`

Please try this. I think it'll work for you.

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is and how this change solves it?

Comment: @DavidReed Actually I was confused about this map , because all values was filling into the Map but when i was using that , Map was getting null value. So i just tried convert to String ,String tyep Map as Rahul Indora mentined above , then it'll be start working.
Thanks Rahul Indora, David and Muzammil for your feedback.